# How do I return a value from a lambda within an AppSync pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-appsync

I have a lambda AppSync resolver which works as I would expect when used as standalone but I can't get it to work within a pipeline.

My lambda code looks like the below.

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    callback(null, myValue);
    return myValue;
}
```

However when I run it within a pipeline I get the following response

```
{
  "data": {
    "updateRoom": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "updateRoom"
      ],
      "data": null,
      "errorType": "MappingTemplate",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 11,
          "column": 3,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "Template transformation yielded an empty response."
    }
  ]
}
```

Edit: I wanted to add an update with some further context. I am now logging the event, context and callback objects in my lambda. They all look as described in the AppSync docs. To keep things simple I output an empty object {} in my lambda right after logging. I am using a js resolver which outputs a hardcoded mock value of the expected type and have removed all other functions. When I remove the lambda function the pipeline returns the mock value. When I add the function in it results in the error above. I have tried verbose AppSync logging, but again I just see the above error.

Answer (score 0):

I am missing some context here but I'll try to answer.
It would be useful to be able to see the full code of the pipeline. Especially the mapping templates/resolvers, including the "before" and "after" templates.

Are you using JS resolver, VTL, or direct Lambda?

One way to debug this is to understand what happens under the hood of each "step" of the process. i.e. what is the content of the context object in every mapping template evaluation (`before`, `request`, `response` and `after`), and what value they return.

One way to do this is to enable AppSync logs (set it to `ALL` and enable verbose content). Then check into CloudWatch what happens in every step of the pipeline.

Or, you can use GraphBolt, an app that I built to solve this kind of issues. It allows you to easily see what happens inside your resolvers.
[See the documentation](https://docs.graphbolt.dev/query-inspector/query-details)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have added an edit with some further context. As mentioned above, everything works fine when just using my lambda. It is only when I try to use the function in the pipeline that the problems start happening.

Comment: Could you share the JS resolvers code?

Comment: import {util} from '@aws-appsync/utils';
export function request(ctx) {return {};}
export function response(ctx) { 
  return {
    createdAt: '2023-03-12T12:59:10.765Z',
    __typename: 'Room',
    name: 'test',
    id: '00b29aa8-9703-44b9-84da-2867553f7407',
    __operation: 'Mutation',
    updatedAt: '2023-03-12T12:59:10.765Z'
  };
}